# Unresponsive elements after button click

Tags: javascript

**Background:**

I started Javascript the other day and built this sketch pad:

http://frankpeelen.github.io/sketch-pad/

following alongside the instructions on:

http://www.theodinproject.com/web-development-101/javascript-and-jquery

**Problem:**

It's basically finished, and works fine except for when creating a new grid with the "New" button. All of a sudden the 'squares' stop responding to 'hover' events. I've searched, but have been unable to find any similar problems. Any ideas?

**Code:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var build = function(h, w) {
  var height = h;
  var width = w;
  //Loop through height to create rows
  for (i = 1; i <= height; i++) {
   $("#sketchpadcontainer").append("<div class='row'></div>");
   //Loop through width to create divs in each row
   for (j = 1; j <= width; j++) {
       $(".row:last-child").append("<div class='sqrcontainer'><div class='square'></div></div>");
      }
  }
 };

 //Build default 16x16 grid
 build(16, 16);

 $("button").click(function() {
  var size = parseInt(prompt("How many squares per side would you like? Please enter a number."));
  //In case the number entered > 50
  if (size > 50) {
   $(".row").remove();
   build(50, 50);
   alert("The number you entered was too large. The number 50 has been used instead.")
  }
  //In case a non-number is entered
  else if (isNaN(size)) {
   $(".row").remove();
   build(16, 16);
   alert("You didn't enter a number. The default of 16 has been used.")
  }
  //In case a number <= 50 is entered
  else {
   $(".row").remove();
   build(size, size);
  }
 })

 $(".square").hover(
 //Mouse in
 function () {
  $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
 },
 //Mouse out
 function () {} );
});
```

```css
html, body, #sitecontainer {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0px;
}

#sketchpadcontainer {
}

button {
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-top: 2em;
 margin-bottom: 1em;
}

#sketchpadcontainer {
}

.row {
 text-align: center;
}

.sqrcontainer {
 height: 1.5em;
 width: 1.5em;
 display: inline-block;
}

.square {
 width: 1em;
 height: 1em;
 margin: .1em;
 border-color: black;
 border-style: solid;
 border-radius: .1em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
 <title>Sketch Pad</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type='text/javascript' src="js/javascript.js"></script>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
 <div id="sitecontainer">
  <div id="buttoncontainer">
   <button type="button">New</button>
  </div>
  <div id="sketchpadcontainer">

  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are deleting the divs before the build method. That means the hover listeners will be deleted to. You have to add them to the .sqare elements again.

Just move

```
$(".square").hover(
//Mouse in
function () {
    $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
},
//Mouse out
function () {} );
```

inside your build method

Comment: readding is much cleaner in my opinion than $(document).on ..... like mentioned above

Comment: ’$(document).on’ needs to added once - and thats why i suggested that way, but everyone write code by himself's mind)

Comment: I see! I didn't know those listeners were 'added', I just thought they 'existed'. Thanks!!

Comment: @Frank-Peelen i adviced u read about .on method, and it different from .click .hover and etc.

Comment: What happens is that you add a callback function on every element with class .square, that is called when the hover event is triggered -> 'Listening for hover'

Answer (score 0):

change `$(".square").hover(`

to     `$(document).on("hover" ,".square", function(){ . . . })`
Ur problem in `$(".square").hover(` - work after `$(document).ready`, but after u appending new rows - document ready dont triggering, and ur elements have not events, and trigger .on work on every elems on page, even on dynamically added.